# How to export FBX models to use in SharpDX?

Tags: models, 3dsmax, sharpdx, fbx, assimp

I am trying to export a model from 3ds Max 2014 as a fbx file and use it in my SharpDX driven project.
In the SharpDX example solution, there is a project named `ModelRendering.Desktop`. I just modified it to load my exported testmodel.

This is the result when running the program:
[image]

As you see, I modeled a cube in 3ds Max. But the sample application shows me something different. When I try to export some more complex models, their renderings are totally broken.

I use the default export settings ("Autodesc Media & Entertainment"). Do I need to hit a special export option or do I need to use some external converter? What is the common way to use fbx models from 3ds Max in SharpDX?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the culling order is correct. This depends on whether you're using LR or RH. If you're not sure, then just try both `GraphicsDevice.RasterizerStates.CullFront` and `GraphicsDevice.RasterizerStates.CullBack` to see which one looks correct.

Also, you might want to try rendering with your camera's world matrix through `Matrix.Transpose`.